# HTML Select Padding Text Issue

Tags: html, css

I have a html select tag and added 25px of padding but when I do that the text disappears. How can I have the  padding but the text still be visible?

Here is my code.

CSS

```
.signup-field {
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

HTML

`<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group">
    <h4 style="color:white; margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:10px;">How did you hear about us?</h4>
      <select class="form-control signup-field" style=""id="sel1">
         <option>1</option>
         <option>2</option>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: You may need share more code. I'm not having that issue just based on the code above.

Comment: I ran your code and it seems to be working fine. Please send the html around the select tag

Comment: I figured out that the reason for my code not working is because of the bootstrap form-control class. Any ideas around that? @PHPDev

Comment: When you are running this code, is it the text in the select drop down that becomes invisible upon padding?

Comment: No it is the text that is supposed to  be in the select field after selecting that disappears @PHPDev

Comment: What text is supposed to be in the select field after selecting? I'd recommend you run the above code independently (out of your project) and see the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141249/discussion-between-phpdev-and-cesarg219).

Answer (score 1):

`Select` elements don't respond to padding like another block-level elements—I wish I knew why. If you're looking to add vertical padding, you can simply swap out `padding` for `height`, and add vertical space that way.

The other option is to use the `appearance` rule to disable some of that default browser styling:

```
.signup-field {
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 25px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

You can see and play around quick a quickie demo here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWZvWE

For a broader explanation of what is and is not possible when styling `select` elements, CSS Tricks has an excellent primer: https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/

#### Edit

For Bootstrap, you'll actually need to use both solutions. Even with the `appearance` rule in place, adding additional padding to a `select` element pushes the value outside the visible frame of the element. BUT, if you apply padding, and then height, you will expand the visible frame, bringing your selected value back into view.

Here's an updated version of the same Code Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWZvWE

Comment: This did not work for me but I figured out that the reason for my code not working is because of the bootstrap form-control class. Any ideas around that?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that Border-radius and padding do not play good if the numbers are not selected wisely. In your example, if your border radius is out of the padding. You can try margins and it will be surely better. However, I did not try it myself. In order to be sure, you can add these to your css file

```
.signup-field {
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 25px;
}
```